# Salesforce JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, salesforce

I'm constructing a button that a user can click once they've opened a case to take ownership and set the status to active. Although I had the code pretty close, but I'm getting an error I'm not familiar with.

Here's my code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/23.0/connection.js")}
var url = parent.location.href; 
var record = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Case)}; //Looking for current case ID
var updateRecord; 

var update_Case = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
update_Case.Id = record;
update_Case.User = {!$User.Id}; 
update_Case.Status = "Active";
updateRecord.push(update_Case);

result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecord);
parent.location.href = url;
```

**I'm getting this error:**

```
A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:
identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
```

Comment: the comment code  is it //  instead of \\ ?

Comment: Yea, sorry about that. I added the comment in the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't get the code you posted to work, but this did:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")}

var updateRecord = new Array(); 
var myquery = "SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id = '{!Case.Id}' limit 1";

result = sforce.connection.query(myquery);
records = result.getArray("records");

if(records[0])
{
    var update_Case = records[0];
    update_Case.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}"; 
    update_Case.Status = "Active";
    updateRecord.push(update_Case);
}

result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecord);
parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
```

Looking at it more, I think the code you posted is erroring because of the `update_Case.User = {!$User.Id};` statement. There is no User field on Case, and the User.Id global variable should be placed in quotes (for JavaScript), like this: `update_Case.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";`

Comment: Thanks Matt, that worked great. It was the global call that was messing me up.

Answer (score 3):

This might save you a query, may be.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")}

var url = parent.location.href;

var update_Case = new sforce.SObject("Case");
update_Case.Id = '{!Case.Id}';
update_Case.OwnerId = '{!$User.Id}'; 
update_Case.Status = 'Active';

result = sforce.connection.update(update_Case);
parent.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")} 
var newRecords = []; 
var c = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
c.id ="{!Case.Id}"; 
c.User = {!$User.Id}; 
c.Status = "Active";
newRecords.push(c); 
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
window.location.reload();`
```